# phantom-jscover produces a TypeError, because phantom.args in not an object

Tags: ant, jasmine, phantomjs, jscoverage

I wants to use jscover for the coverage report i followed the manual but getting the exception :

> **TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'phantom.args[0]')**

following are the files i am using :

js-code-coverage.xml content:

```
        <!-- running jscover for the code coverage -->
    <target name="startjscoverserver">
        <java jar="${jsCover}/JSCover-all.jar" fork="true" spawn="true">
            <jvmarg value="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8" />  
            <arg value="-ws" />
            <arg value="--document-root=${documentRoot}" />
            <arg value="--report-dir=${reports}/coverage" />
            <arg value="--no-instrument=${documentRoot}/resources/public"/>
            <arg value="--no-            instrument=${documentRoot}/resources/knockoutComponents"/>
            <arg value="--no- instrument=${documentRoot}/resources/public/common"/>
            <arg value="--no-function"/>
            <arg value="--port=8080" />
        </java>

        <waitfor maxwait="5" maxwaitunit="second" checkevery="250" checkeveryunit="millisecond" timeoutproperty="failed">
            <http url="http://localhost:8080/jscoverage.html" />
        </waitfor>
        <fail if="failed" />

        <echo message="JSCover has been run. URL: http://localhost:8080/jscoverage.html" />

    </target>



    <!-- starting the code coverage -->
    <target name="jscodecoverage">
        <exec executable="${phantomJS}/${phantomPath}" failonerror="false">
            <arg line="${phantomJS}/phantom-jscover.js" />
            <arg line="http://localhost:8080/jscoverage.html?http://localhost:7001/myproject/JasmineSpecRunner.html" /> 
        </exec>
    </target>
```

and the phantom-jscover.js :

```js
(function() {
   function waitFor(testFx, onReady) {
    var condition = false, interval = setInterval(function() {
        if (!condition) {
            condition = (typeof (testFx) === 'string' ? eval(testFx)
                    : testFx());
        } else {
            if (typeof (onReady) === 'string') {
                eval(onReady);
            } else {
                onReady();
            }
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, 100);
}

var url  = phantom.args[0];

var page = require('webpage').create();
var fs   = require('fs');

page.onCallback = function(data) {
    if ('jasminelog' === data.message) {
        fs.write('/dev/stdout', data.data.message, 'w');
    }
};

page.open(url, function(status) {
    if (status !== "success") {
        phantom.exit(1);
    } else {
        waitFor(function() {

            return page.evaluate(function() {
                var reporter = window.jsApiReporter;
                if (window.frames[0]) {
                    reporter = window.frames[0].jsApiReporter;
                }
                return reporter && reporter.finished;
            });
        }, function() {
            page.evaluate(function() {
                var jscoverage_report = window.jscoverage_report;

                if (window.frames[0]) {
                    jscoverage_report = window.frames[0].jscoverage_report;
                }

                if (jscoverage_report) {
                    jscoverage_report('phantom');
                }
            });
            phantom.exit(0);
        });
    }
  });
 }).call(this);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was probably written for an older version of PhantomJS. [`phantom.args` is deprecated](http://phantomjs.org/api/phantom/property/args.html).

The workaround is to use the system module:

```
var url = require('system').args[1];
```

Note:

> The first one is always the script name, which is then followed by the subsequent arguments.